# In R shiny, how to show image in rows instead of text automatically?

Tags: r, shiny

using this data I've created a matrix and now I need to replace text in both column names and row name with logos to end up with the attached result [image]
here is some of logo icons 
[car](https://static.thenounproject.com/png/2761392-200.png), [tv](https://static.thenounproject.com/png/149841-200.png), 
please use this [data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VrzH91HwtWKkkpea1VCTptA2eqIRC2Ia)

here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

testmatrix <- readxl::read_xlsx("testmatrix.xlsx")

ui <- fluidPage(
dataTableOutput("myTable")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
logoList = data.frame(
name = c("opel", "kia", "bmw"),
logo = c"<img height='50' src='https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/opel-2-202862.png'></img>",
  "<img height='50' src='https://www.logospng.com/images/88/royal-azure-blue-kia-icon-free-car-logo-88484.png'></img>",
  "<img height='50' src='https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/bmw-4-202746.png'></img>"
),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
myData = reactiveVal( {
logo_name_match <- merge(
x = data.frame(
row_id = 1:length(colnames(testmatrix)),
cols = rownames(testmatrix), 
stringsAsFactors = FALSE
), 
y = logoList, 
by.x = "cols", 
by.y = "name", 
all.x = TRUE
)
logo_name_match <- logo_name_match[with(logo_name_match, order(col_id)), ]
row_colnames <- ifelse(!is.na(logo_name_match$logo), logo_name_match$logo, logo_name_match$cols)
rownames(testmatrix) <- new_row testmatrix
})
output$myTable = renderDataTable({
myData = myData()
datatable(myData, escape = FALSE)
})}
```

Comment: Dear, I need to replace the text with logo, each table my  contain several rows so it's must be automatic "find and replace" from the excel sheet to the dashboard
not one by one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were some mistakes in your code. Using images of logos in a DataTable column seems not to be a problem, once the data frame is arranged properly. Next step is to figure out how to use images or icons in column names. Not sure how to do it yet, but if I find an answer I will update the code below. Note, that I added the dplyr package, since I rewrote the part where you merge the image links with your data. Further, I used dput() to put the data of your testmatrix as inside the code, so other users do not need to download the data to reproduce your example.

**Update:** Adding images to DataTable column names was easier then expected. The closing img-tag made some problems so I just cut it off. Does not seem to be a problem.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)

testmatrix <-
  structure(
    list(
      brand = c(
        "kia",
        "vw",
        "mit",
        "bmw",
        "audi",
        "lw",
        "lada",
        "RR",
        "opel",
        "LBGN",
        "Jeep"
      ),
      g.rank = c(1, 2, 3, 6,
                 5, 4, 8, 10, 9, 12, 11),
      `No. Of Cars` = c(180, 159, 156, 164,
                        198, 191, 192, 155, 167, 185, 156),
      generation_z = c(37, 66,
                       72, 37, 2, 32, 19, 88, 49, 83, 43),
      generation_x = c(80, 59,
                       56, 64, 98, 91, 92, 55, 67, 85, 56),
      generation_y = c(94, 4,
                       1, 7, 47, 99, 34, 68, 81, 69, 97),
      other = c(1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4,
                8, 10, 9, 12, 11)
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-11L),
    class = c("tbl_df",
              "tbl", "data.frame")
  )

shinyApp(

ui = fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput("myTable")
),

server = function(input, output, session) {

  logoList = data.frame(
    name = c("opel", "kia", "bmw"),
    logo = c("<img height='50' src='https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/opel-2-202862.png'></img>",
    "<img height='50' src='https://www.logospng.com/images/88/royal-azure-blue-kia-icon-free-car-logo-88484.png'></img>",
    "<img height='50' src='https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/bmw-4-202746.png'></img>"
  ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

myData = reactive({

  testmatrix %>% 
    inner_join(logoList, by = c("brand" = "name")) %>% 
    dplyr::select(
           manufacturer = logo,
           `<img height='25' src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/63/63337.svg'>` = generation_z,
           everything(),
           -brand)

})

output$myTable = renderDataTable({ 

  print(myData())

  datatable(myData(), escape = FALSE)

})
}
)
```

Comment: thanks for your effort, can you please amend it to be extracted from the excel sheet, as this is just a sample the actual data wide larger and must be dynamic and automatically  updated

Comment: Just replace in your code the right hand side of `textmatrix <-` with `readxl::read_xlsx("testmatrix.xlsx")`. SO is for people to learn and it helps other users to run this code, since 99% won't download your data and in a couple of years the link to your data might not exist anymore so its better to keep it the way it is.

Comment: Thanks Again TimTeaFan, can't thank you enough :)
in this code name=(c(,,,,) must equal the number of links in other word if there is no hyperlink for one of the brand the whole raw disappear.
and its not dynamic to read each row and updating automatically.
please bear with me

Comment: Since I used an inner_join rows which are not the logoList disappear, but that is easily changed into a left join together with an ifelse statement that returns the name as text for manufacturers with missing symbols. I will update that later. The part where you want to update the table dynamically you would need to elaborate a bit more. What data is given at the start of the app? Does data change while the app is running and if yes how? ... etc